# Equivalent of $(this) reference of jquery, in vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, reference

In jquery , I can use $(this) reference to access an element without using any class or id. What is the way to achieve similar result in vue.js?

Comment: provide a minimal reproducible example of what actual problem you are solving.  your comments imply that you are misunderstanding the basic concepts of designing a web app using Vue

Comment: In vue, you do not imperatively target DOM nodes to manipulate like you might in jQuery.  You have a well-formed data structure that backs what you will render, usually in the form of a tree, that is propagated into your components, also usually structured in a hierarchy with components given selected nodes in said tree, which deterministically render based on the data given.  You can then independently change the backing data, which the components will render and in the case of Vue automatically update from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want to get an element which triggered event. Then it should be `event.target`.

For example:

```
<div @click="sayHi"></div>
```

---

```
methods: {
 sayHi(event) {
 console.log(event.target)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The prior answer refers to `this.$el` which grabs the root element of a given Vue component ([Vue documentation on .el](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#el)), however, if you want to grab an arbitrary element within a given component, you can use `this.$refs` ([Vue documentation on .refs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref)):

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1 ref="myHeader">Hello</h1>
  <div>
<template>
```

Comment: by referencing the data props or state that was used to render your component. you should not be depending on dom node references to manage your model

Comment: I generally agree with your sentiment, but the question wasn't "should I be doing this"? :)

Comment: The only time I've really needed to use DOM nodes was doing some complex scrolling behavior using .scrollTop for a combo box I was creating. Otherwise, I agree, using Vue native event handlers and props/data is the way to go.

Answer (score -1):

`this.$el` within a Vue component

Comment: If I have multiple element, with same @click event,  how can I know, the event trigger from which element?

Comment: For example, I have some paragraph element,  and I call a delete methods on @click event. In delete methods how can I get the information from which particular information the event has been triggered?

Comment: `<p v-for="paragraph in paragraphs" :key="paragraph.id" @click="delete(paragraph.id)">{{ paragraph.content }}</p>`

`methods: {
  delete(id) {
    this.paragraphs.splice(this.paragraphs.findIndex(p => p.id === id), 1)
  }
}`

Comment: Or if you really don't have ids on you paragraphs (and it's ok as long as you don't have some reordering): `<p v-for="(paragraph, index) in paragraphs" :key="index" @click="delete(paragraph)">{{ paragraph.content }}</p>`

`methods: {
  delete(index) {
    this.paragraphs.splice(index, 1)
  }
}`

Comment: Consider expanding your answer by editing it, instead of using comments.